# Is there a way to keep people from cheating a pedometer?

Tags: android, google-fit

I want to create an android app that involves keeping track of your steps however it will be crucial to the app that the person will not be able to increase the steps taken by shaking their phone. Is there any method to make sure that the person is actually moving and not just shaking their phone

Comment: well there is always the possibility of tracking their location and compare it to the starting point to see the total distance they've moved, but i guess this cannot be the most accurate approach.

Comment: No. All pedometers are actually quite unreliable.